# Mistake in reasoning: $Pv\frac{1}{x} = 0$??

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm making some mistake in my reasoning, which leads to $Pv\frac{1}{x} = 0$ (in distributional sense):

$$<Pv\frac{1}{x},\phi> = lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}(\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{a}\frac{\phi}{x}dx)$$
Where I made use of the fact that $\phi$ is a test function with compact support in $[-a,a]$.
If I define:
$$f(\epsilon) = (\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{a}\frac{\phi}{x}dx)$$
Then:
$$<Pv\frac{1}{x},\phi> = lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}f(\epsilon)$$
I now reason that for all $\epsilon$, I can write:
$$f(\epsilon) \leq \vert\vert\phi\vert\vert_{[-a,a]}(\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx) \triangleq \vert\vert\phi\vert\vert_{[-a,a]}g(\epsilon) $$
Where $\vert\vert\phi\vert\vert_{[-a,a]}$ is the supremum norm of $\phi$.
Also: 
$$f(\epsilon) \geq -\vert\vert\phi\vert\vert_{[-a,a]}(\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx) \triangleq \vert\vert\phi\vert\vert_{[-a,a]}g(\epsilon) $$
If I use now that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}g(\epsilon) = Pv\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{x} = 0$$
then $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}f(\epsilon) = 0 = <Pv\frac{1}{x},\phi>$$
Which can't be right. I would be glad if someone could find the mistake for me, because I don't see it.

Comment: $f(\epsilon)\leq \|\phi\|\left(\left|\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx\right|+\left|\int_{\epsilon}^{a} \frac{1}{x}dx\right|\right)$ which tends to infinity as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$. You cannot take the sup norm out of the integral without also taking some absolute value along the way...

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse! Thank you